# How to ask the end-user fill all the default colums in a form when upload a new document without uploading and then editing it?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, upload, modal-dialog, document

I've a library call documental centre where the end-users have to upload all the files they want to publish. But I would like to ask them to fill all the default columns without creating a new type of content or uploading and then editing it, is that posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all many people create a new type of content and it helps but, really?

The easy way to ask the user fill all the defaults columns only has to follow 4 simple steps (clicks).

Step 1: Go to the Library Tap (in spanish "Biblioteca"

[Step 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1yLn.png) Click on Library Configuration (in spanish "Configuración de Biblioteca")

Step 3: Click on Advanced Configuration (in Spanish "Configuración Avanzada")

[Step 4, the last but not least:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q37Z0.png) On Content Type chooses "Yes" (in Spanish "Tipo de Contenido" -> "Sí")

That's it...

GOOD LUCK!!